# Is there a way to set chip background colors randomly, programmatically?

Tags: android, colors, background

I have been messing with the coloring on chips in a ChipGroup in my app, and have been trying to set the background color. I would like to make each chip a random color picked from a range before putting into the chipgroup, but can't figure out how to do it.

I have an rgb color being randomly generated no problem, but I can't figure out how to set the color of the chip. Normally, it looks like you set a Chip's background color using `setChipBackroundColor(ColorStateList)`, but `ColorStateList` specifically seems to want resource ids for colors...

Any ideas of what I could do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ColorStateList.valueOf()` inside the `setChipBackgroundColor()` function. Here is an example code.

```
Chip chip = findViewById(R.id.chip);

Random rnd = new Random();

int color = Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));

chip.setChipBackgroundColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem! I didn't realize that int value given to valueof was actually the whole color stored into an int.

Comment: @A.Snarr You are welcome! Color is represented by a red, green and blue component as a hexadecimal number in the form RedRedGreenGreenBlueBlue (like 180CFF). Programming languages lika Java can use it as an integer value since hexadecimal numbers can be converted, for your information.